# how to show datatable header to gridview header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to show the datatable header to gridview header. 
      My datatable have dynamic header it may be changeable so i want to show that header as a gridview header. please help me to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the GridView's [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) property to `true`(what is the default).

You could also generate them manually with AutoGenerateColumns set to `false`:

```
   foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
   {    
       BoundField field = new BoundField();
       field.DataField = col.ColumnName;
       field.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
       GridView1.Columns.Add(field);
   }
   GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   GridView1.DataSource = tbl; //a DataTable of your choice
   GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: @Fernando: Edited my answer. So either set AutoGenerateColumns to true, set your DataTable as DataSource of the GridView and DataBind it or set AutoGenerateColumns to false, create the columns dynamically and then set the DataSource+DataBind the Grid(see code above)

Comment: Gridview repeat again and again horizontally when button click.I can't fix this error. please help me

Comment: @Fernando:  You should only create the columns if `!Page.IsPostback` in page_load. I assume that you've missed that.

Answer (score 0):

use this code before initializing datatable;

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
 $.fn.dataTable.tables({ visible: true, api: true }).columns.adjust();
});
```